# Validated JSON throwing SyntaxError: Property must be a string literal

Tags: javascript, json, syntax-error, parse-error

I have a validated JSON that I'm pulling into my app, but as soon as I choose an item related to the JSON the app just goes into a forever "loading" cycle.

The error I receive is `Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Property name must be a string literal`.

Here is my validated JSON:

```
{
    "lodges": [
                
        {
        "title": "Lakeside Lodge",
        "url_title": "lakeside-lodge",                      
        "lodges_short_name": "Lakeside",
        "lodges_description": "<h5><strong>Coming Soon: Estimated Opening Fall 2021 </strong></h5><p>The Lakeside Lodge sits will rest in the center of this premier state park, <a href=\"/parks/lakeside\">Lakeside State Park</a>.</p>",
        "lodges_summary": "<p>Anticipated opening in Fall 2021, the new 85-room Lodge at Lakeside State Park!</p>",
        "reservation_link": "null"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the code I am using to get and display in the data:

```
showAmenities(item){
    let list : any;
    let res : any;
    switch (item) {
      case 'lodges':
         this.data.getParkLodges(this.park).then(data => {
            let res = JSON.parse(data);
            let list = res.lodges;
            this.openAmenityListPage(item,list);
         }
    }
}

openAmenityListPage(item,list){
  let amenitiesModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ParkAmenitiesListPage, {title : item, listItems: list, park: this.parkDetails.title, parkShortName: this.parkShortName });
  amenitiesModal.present();   
}
```

I am able to get data and display other JSON's that are identical, but for some reason this one is throwing this error.

Edit: I am working with other APIs with HTML tags within their values, and those are working perfectly fine.

Comment: I don't have a comma at the end of the last line

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string contains escaped double quotes: `<a href=\"/parks/lakeside\">`.
The escaping "gets lost" as soon as the JSON code is interpreted as a string by Javascript. Escaped quotes in a string become normal quotes:

```
console.log('a text with \"quotes\".') // --> logs 'a text with "quotes"'.
```

So in your case, the actual string that `JSON.parse()` sees, and that leads to a parse error, is like:

```
'{ "lodges_description": "<a href="/parks/lakeside">" }, ...'
```

You need to escape the escape character, so that Javascript knows you want to pass the actual backslash character to the `JSON.parse()` function:

```
console.log('a text with \\"quotes\\".') // --> logs 'a text with \"quotes\"'.
```

Comment: this is a really great point @kicia but there are other APIs I'm working with that also have HTML tags within their values and they work perfectly... this is certainly a tricky one I'll admit.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with HTML tags or escaped quotes. Just tricky to follow up where they get 'expanded'. At which point(s) does the JSON get converted to string, before it is returned from `getParkLodges` ? (You have posted a JSON example, but `data` is a JSON-string, not a JSON)

Comment: Turns out there was a relationship API with a channel I was working with that contained an extra comma. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a relationship API with a channel I was working with that contained an extra comma. :D

This question is closed.

Comment: you may mark your own answer as 'accepted', so that it doesn't show up in searches for to-be-solved questions.